# Lambda function MySQL result not working on NodeJs 8.10

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a code in Node 6.10 and it is working...
But If I convert it to Node 8.10 it's not working

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: " localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "parser_db"
});

exports.handler = async event => {
  connection.connect();

  let response = {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: { Method: "Invalid", event }
  };

  var readTable = "SELECT * FROM documents where id = " + mysql.escape(1);
  connection.query(readTable, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: { results }
        //body: { results }
      };
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }
  });
};
```

Can some one please help me to detect the problem. It is also not working if I do the MySQL query in separate file and return the result set.

> Note : If I print the result using console.log(response) instead returning it's
>   showing the correct result.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the problem than "it is not working"? That doesn't give anyone much to go on.

Comment: I mean it's not returning any result... Code execution is fine... I have mentioned in note @BobRodes

Comment: Let me change that. Where you you put `console.log`? Right by the `return response` line?

Comment: Please check the code now... response printing in console but not returning anything... @BobRodes

Comment: The problem is that you are returning response from within the connection.query() callback function. That makes response the return value for the callback function, not the return value for the outer Lambda function's exports.handler().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning response from within the connection.query() callback function. That makes response the return value for the callback function, not the return value for the outer Lambda function.

One way to restructure this code is as follows:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  connection.connect();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const readTable = `SELECT * FROM documents where id = ${mysql.escape(1)}`;
    connection.query(readTable, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve({statusCode: 200, body: {results}});
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jarmod's answer, You can also use the [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) method to promisify `connection.query` so that you can use the `await` keyword, to make the code simpler

```
const util = require('util');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  connection.connect();
  const readTable = `SELECT * FROM documents where id = ${mysql.escape(1)}`;
  const connQueryPromisified = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
  const result = await connQueryPromisified(readTable);
  return {statusCode: 200, body: {results}};
};
```